# Is there a constant for the move directory up string

Tags: c#, path

Is there a platform-specific string for the *"move directory up"* string `..` like there is `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` for the seperation of directory levels?

If not why and is it safe to use `..` on any platform?

Comment: The only field in Path are : 
      Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar: `'/'`,
 Path.DirectorySeparatorChar: `'\'`,
    Path.GetInvalidPathChars: {a lot},
    Path.PathSeparator: `';'`,
    Path.VolumeSeparatorChar: ':'. I didn't knew they was a platform specific **`..`**